# How do i make this smaller

Tags: html

```
<div class="box">
            <a href="https://youtu.be/s6zR2T9vn2c" class="image fit"><img src="images/pic01.png" alt="" /></a>
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>mBrowse Builds </h3>
                <p>Offical Builds for mBrowse . To download go click "Visit page" button</p>
                <form method="get" action="mbrowse build 1-420.zip">
                    <button type="submit">Download!</button>
```

How do i make this smaller like 800px by 800px

Comment: What you mean "this"? Please, make the code reproducible including css used.

Answer (score 0):

If "this" means to the `div`, Add `width` and `height` properties to that:

```html
<div class="box" width="800" height="800">
            <a href="https://youtu.be/s6zR2T9vn2c" class="image fit"><img src="images/pic01.png" alt="" /></a>
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>mBrowse Builds </h3>
                <p>Offical Builds for mBrowse . To download go click "Visit page" button</p>
                <form method="get" action="mbrowse build 1-420.zip">
                    <button type="submit">Download!</button>
<!--Continuation of the code-->
```

A better way is to add the `width` and `height` properties to the class:

```html
<div class="box">
            <a href="https://youtu.be/s6zR2T9vn2c" class="image fit"><img src="images/pic01.png" alt="" /></a>
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>mBrowse Builds </h3>
                <p>Offical Builds for mBrowse . To download go click "Visit page" button</p>
                <form method="get" action="mbrowse build 1-420.zip">
                    <button type="submit">Download!</button>
<!--Continuation of the code-->
```

```css
.box {
 width: 800px;
 height: 800px;
}
```